# python script for measuring battery time

Tags: python, time, battery

I was looking for a script to log battery time (i.e. total time laptop runs on battery). I thought I'd give writing one a shot in python. I'm an beginner at python and came up with this using a lot of examples from this site :D

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess, os
from datetime import datetime

time = (datetime.now()).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
date = (datetime.today()).strftime('%d/%m/%y')

def start(x):
    if x[2] == 'Discharging' and int(x[3][:-1]) in range(98, 101):

        batt_log = open('/home/saad/Code/batt_log', 'w')
        batt_log.write(time + '%s' %(os.linesep))
        batt_log.close()

def end(x):
    if x[2] == 'Discharging' and int(x[3][:-1]) in range(1, 11):

        batt_log = open('/home/saad/Code/batt_log', 'a')
        batt_log.write(time)
        batt_log.close()

def main():

    output = subprocess.check_output('acpi -b', shell=True)
    l = (output.replace(',', '')).split(' ')

    if not (l[2] in ['Charging', 'Full'] or int(l[3][:-1]) in range(11, 98)):
        start(l)
        end(l)
        ts = []     
        batt_log = open('/home/saad/Code/batt_log', 'r')
        all_lines = batt_log.readlines()
        for line in all_lines:
            ts.append(line.replace(os.linesep, ''))

        if len(ts) > 1:
            FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
            tdelta = datetime.strptime(ts[1], FMT) - datetime.strptime(ts[0], FMT)
            batt_store = open('/home/saad/Code/batt_store', 'a')
            batt_store.write(date + '\nTotal Time: ' + str(tdelta) + '\n')
            batt_store.close()

    batt_store = open('/home/saad/Code/batt_store', 'r')    
    all_lines = batt_store.readlines()
    print "Last Battery Time:", all_lines[-1][-8:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script actually works but I'd like it to be better. It uses system acpi command to get battery stats, writes them to one file (batt_log) to store start and end times, then reads from that file, calculates the time difference and writes it to another file (batt_store). I run it every 5 minutes as a process.

What I'd like to do is to maybe use less file I/O operations and find a way to store values persistently in the program. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Since your script works, don't be surprised if this gets closed, as there isn't a direct "problem" to fix, per se.  However, I think it is a good question.  Is there any reason you want to use less I/O?

Comment: just seems repetitive and inelegant :)

Comment: would there be any way to trigger the program when battery reaches a specific level? instead of running it for hours with nothing to do it could run only when needed. Because for once it records start_time it has to wait 3 hours to record an end_time to get something useful.

Comment: posted updated script on blog koogee.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

Getting data through command is far easier. In essence what acpi command would be doing is opening a file descriptor on specific file node in /dev/ . You could look at dbus interfaces for getting the information.

Regarding opening and closing of files, you could again use services like dbus or gconf but it is just easier writing a file.

Comment: I think messing with OS internals is a bit above my skill. I'd have to get familiar with dbus bindings etc but thanks for your input.